# Querying String Values in Pure JavaScript AND Opening a Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, I found this code on another thread

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values), and it's been very helpful in location a string value in a URL.  Now I need to take that string value, and use it to open a dialog box.

Here is the original code to get the string value

```
 function getParameterByName( name )
{
name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
if( results == null )
return "";
else
return results[1];
}
```

and here is the code I've written to search for the string, and open the dialog box, and yet it is not doing that.

```
var signup_param = getParameterByName( 'Redirect' );
if (signup_param == "signup") {
$('#emailDuplicateDialog').dialog('open');
}
```

The URL I'm working with btw ends with login.html?redirect=signup so redirect is the name, and signup is the value.

Any suggestions on changes to make this work would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getParameterByName( 'Redirect' )` shouldn't be `getParameterByName( 'redirect' )`?

Also, you can debug the variable `signup_param` to see it's value.

Comment: So the problem must be on the dialog. Check if everything is ok.